# logstash geoip filter returns _geoip_lookup_failure

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, geoip

i am working on logstash . i have installed successfully logstash-filter-geoip

but when i tried to use this it returns _geoip_lookup_failure
thi is in my logstash.conf file

```
filter{
    geoip {
    source => "clientip"
  }
}
```

this is my input for logstash

```
 55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043
```

it it returns

```
{
    "duration" => "0.043",
    "request" => "/index.html",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-07-25T14:33:30.495Z,
    "method" => "GET",
    "bytes" => "15824",
    "@version" => "1",
    "host" => "DEs-0033",
    "client" => "55.3.244.1",
    "message" => "55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043",
    "tried to use this it returns _geoip_lookup_failuretags" => [
        [0] "_geoip_lookup_failure"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a field `clientip`? I does not appears in your example.

Answer (score 0):

try `client` instead of `clientip`.

```
filter{
    geoip {
    source => "client"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `clientip` field does not exist in your case. You will have to use `client` field.

On the other hand, you may check on [IP2Location filter plugin tutorial](https://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ip2location-filter-plugin-with-elk)  that provide example as what you are doing. For example:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
  }
  ip2location {
    source => "clientip"
  }
}
```